# Создание userdata из произвольной структуры в lua

Tags: c, lua

Возникла необходимость создать `userdata` из произвольной структуры, которая задана как

```
struct uinput_user_dev {
    char name[UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    struct input_id id;
    __u32 ff_effects_max;
    __s32 absmax[ABS_CNT];
    __s32 absmin[ABS_CNT];
    __s32 absfuzz[ABS_CNT];
    __s32 absflat[ABS_CNT];
};
```

(это определение из заголовка `uinput.h`).
Однако, lua требует описания вида

```
typedef struct имя {
    тип1 поле1
    ...
} имя;
```

Что означает дублироваие имени, и как создать `userdata` из "обычной" структуры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задекларируйте нужную структуру как тип следующим образом:

```
typedef struct имя имя;
```